# Segfault in the use of sprintf

Tags: string, printf

I am trying to read from a packet payload just its User agent.

I am searching for "User-Agent" in packet payload and and from then on copying as many chars as there are between the occurrence of "User-Agent" and the first occurrence of '\n' right after that. Here's my code:

```
sprintf(
   stat,"%.*s\0",
   strstr(strstr(p->data, "User-Agent:"),"\n") - strstr(p->data, "User-Agent:"),
   strstr(p->data, "User-Agent: ")
);
```

The trouble is that for a LOT of packets, this is causing seg fault. I am sorry for this silly way to write it; if you know a better way to write (or format), please tell me.

Comment: I think you just have to consider what happens if any of those strings are not found.

Comment: And what did your debugger tell you? Valgrind? What debugging have you performed so far? Do you have a testcase?

Comment: you do this twice: `strstr(p->data, "User-Agent:"),"\n")`. I would store the result in variable and reuse it.

Comment: What happens if your p->data does not contain "user-agent"? Looks crazy:
`sprintf(stat,"%.*s\0", strstr(NULL, "\n") - NULL, NULL)`

Comment: @guetti I actually use 'strstr(p->data, "User-Agent:"),"\n")' just once. And you're right, there are a million packets which don't have user agents, that's why this snippet is inside an if clause which ensures that this code is executed only if User-Agent is present in the p->data.

Comment: @Tomalak Gerek'kal the debugger told me that p is optimized out, though I edited the Makefile and changed -O2 to -O0. Same thing.

Comment: You have memory corruption somewhere. Make a testcase.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing code that is so complex? The pointer arthritic could end end pointing to something that will give a seg fault. Consider refactoring the code.